# Restful service with Netbeans not working

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, glassfish

Please I have been stuck in this for day now. I am learning to develop web services in Java. I followed deitel's book and have created a restful service as stipulated. But after deployment, testing doesn't work. No navigation bar on the testing page. I also created a client to consume the service but the restxml service wasn't found.

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2   jdk 1.8.    And glassfish 4.0
I was following the book "java how to program" the example at 31.7.1 creating a REST-Based XML Web service.NetBeans provides various templates for creating RESTful web services, including ones
that can interact with databases on the client’s behalf. In this chapter, we focus on simple
RESTful web services.                                                                      To create a RESTful web service:

1.Right-click the WelcomeRESTXML node in the Projects tab, and select New > Other…to display theNew Filedialog.

2.Select Web Services under Categories,then select RESTful Web Services from Patterns and clickNext >.

3.Under Select Pattern,ensure Simple Root Resource is selected, and click Next.

4.Set the Resource Package to com.deitel.welcomerestxml, the Path to welcome   and the Class Name to WelcomeRESTXMLResource.Leave the MIME Type and Representation Class set to application/xml and java.lang.String, respectively. The correct configuration is shown in Fig. 31.11.

5.Click Finish to create the web service.

Comment: Please mention which example from which book you are following. Also explain how you deployed and started the service.

Comment: I was following the book "java how to program" the example at 31.7.1 creating a REST-Based XML Web service.